# POI single vs multithreaded performance

Tags: java, excel, multithreading, apache-poi

I have a pretty simple use case - read an Excel spreadsheet with POI, populate some values, run cell updates and retrieve calculation outputs.

What puzzles me is performance. If I run single-threaded, Excel file takes a few seconds to get loaded/parsed, but for each subsequent request processing time decreases. If I run exactly the task via multiple threads and then join, the performance is actually 10 times slower on all threads. Where am I messing up?

Here is the test output:

```
Running Multi Threaded
Thread Thread-8 finished run 7092
Thread Thread-9 finished run 7092
Thread Thread-7 finished run 7092
Thread Thread-10 finished run 7092
Thread Thread-4 finished run 7092
Thread Thread-5 finished run 7092
Thread Thread-3 finished run 7107
Thread Thread-2 finished run 7107
Thread Thread-6 finished run 7107
Thread Thread-1 finished run 7108
Finished in 7113

Running Single Threaded
Thread Thread-11 finished run 591
Thread Thread-12 finished run 192
Thread Thread-13 finished run 173
Thread Thread-14 finished run 149
Thread Thread-15 finished run 126
Thread Thread-16 finished run 133
Thread Thread-17 finished run 159
Thread Thread-18 finished run 124
Thread Thread-19 finished run 131
Thread Thread-20 finished run 121
Finished in 1907
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the test:

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class PerfTest {

    @Test
    public void runSingleThreaded() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Running Single Threaded");

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new PoiThread().run();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }

    @Test
    public void runMultiThreaded() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Running Multi Threaded");

        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            threads.add(new PoiThread());
        }

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        threads.forEach(t -> t.start());
        threads.forEach(t -> {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }

    public static class PoiThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                long runStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/customer.xlsx")));
                Helper helper = new Helper(workbook, "test", workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator());
                String ref = helper.getFieldValueCellReference("Inputs", "customer");
                helper.evaluateAllCells();
                Map<String, Double> premiums = helper.getAllNumericFields("Premium Outputs");
                System.out.println(String.format("Thread %s finished run %s", this.getName(), (System.currentTimeMillis() - runStart)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Guessing at contention for one file, try 10 copies.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look @trashgod! Same results with 10 different files :( . Running multithreading via Executor seems to perform a bit better, but still the same patter...

Comment: POI XSSF uses loads of memory - so processing multiple files in parallel could be leading to extra GC and general memory contention - could you try running with a higher Xmx? - Really, the only way to get this right is through trial and error - increasing/decreasing the number of files processed in parallel and increasing memory settings as far as you can - if you want fast xlsx processing, you might be better to use https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel or https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader or some other lib that worries more about fast processing

Comment: Me not a thread expert, but I believe this only shows the memory overhead and the overhead of CPU usage of holding the 10 threads in a list in memory. I suspect it doesn't matter what happens in the threads. Try simply something else than using `XSSFWorkbook` in the threads. I suspect even then each thread will run slower in your `runMultiThreaded` than in your `runSingleThreaded`.

Answer (score 0):

Huge thank you to all who've taken a look !

Looks like there are some caching/performance optimizations (JIT/C2?) happening at JVM/OS level that result in significant performance gains. Single threaded starts slow, and then picks up very quickly. Same for multi-threaded, each thread starts slow then picks up. If we start 10 threads - each starts with the worst performance, but then improves with subsequent runs.

So repeating each test 10 times (i.e. 100 files) will actually result in much better overall multi-threaded performance. It ends up being twice as fast as single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your test case shows what you think it does.

Both of your methods, `runSingleThreaded` as well as `runMultiThreaded`, are running multi threaded. The only difference is that in your `runMultiThreaded` each thread uses `Thread.join` to wait for this thread to die. Furthermore your `runMultiThreaded` increases the memory overhead by storing all thread objects in a list in memory. So it is not really surprising that your `runMultiThreaded` performs worse.

Consider the following code:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class PerfTest {

    public void runSingleThreaded() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Running Single Threaded");

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            doTheWork("Work " + i);
        }
        
        System.out.println(String.format("runSingleThreaded finished in %s millis.", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    }

    public void runMultiThreaded() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Running Multi Threaded");

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread t = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            t = new PoiThread();
            t.start();
        }
        
        // wait until last thread is finished
        if (t != null) t.join();
        
        System.out.println(String.format("runMultiThreaded finished in %s millis.", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    }
    
    public static void doTheWork(String workName) throws Throwable {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExampleIn.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
        in.close();
        workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
        workbook.close();
        System.out.println(String.format("%s finished in %s millis.", workName, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    }

    public static class PoiThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                doTheWork(this.getName());          
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        //XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); workbook.close();
        
        PerfTest test = new PerfTest();
        test.runSingleThreaded();
        //test.runMultiThreaded();
    }
}
```

Here the `runSingleThreaded` really runs single threaded, means all in main thread. The `runMultiThreaded` starts threads and only waits for the last started thread to die.

If started using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    //XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); workbook.close();
    
    PerfTest test = new PerfTest();
    test.runSingleThreaded();
    //test.runMultiThreaded();
}
```

It prints:

```
Running Single Threaded
Work 0 finished in 1850 millis.
Work 1 finished in 434 millis.
Work 2 finished in 396 millis.
Work 3 finished in 409 millis.
Work 4 finished in 351 millis.
Work 5 finished in 378 millis.
Work 6 finished in 368 millis.
Work 7 finished in 371 millis.
Work 8 finished in 318 millis.
Work 9 finished in 305 millis.
runSingleThreaded finished in 5199 millis.
```

Why the first work takes longer? This is because while first instantiating `apache poi` classes, as well as most other classes, super-ordinate tasks are running which need to run only once for each thread. For example to prepare the environment.

If started using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    //XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); workbook.close();
    
    PerfTest test = new PerfTest();
    //test.runSingleThreaded();
    test.runMultiThreaded();
}
```

It prints:

```
Running Multi Threaded
Thread-2 finished in 3743 millis.
Thread-8 finished in 3747 millis.
Thread-5 finished in 3747 millis.
Thread-0 finished in 3747 millis.
Thread-9 finished in 3745 millis.
Thread-3 finished in 3745 millis.
Thread-7 finished in 3744 millis.
Thread-6 finished in 3744 millis.
Thread-1 finished in 3744 millis.
Thread-4 finished in 3743 millis.
runMultiThreaded finished in 3752 millis.
```

Here the super-ordinate tasks are running for each thread. But in whole it is faster than the single threaded processing.

Some of the super-ordinate tasks could be done before the main work starts. Using `apache poi` for example one could triggering the super-ordinate tasks, which will be in main thread only, by instantiating a main `apache poi` class.

If started using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); workbook.close();
    
    PerfTest test = new PerfTest();
    //test.runSingleThreaded();
    test.runMultiThreaded();
}
```

it prints:

```
Running Multi Threaded
Thread-0 finished in 2799 millis.
Thread-4 finished in 2805 millis.
Thread-2 finished in 2803 millis.
Thread-7 finished in 2800 millis.
Thread-5 finished in 2801 millis.
Thread-1 finished in 2800 millis.
Thread-8 finished in 2798 millis.
Thread-9 finished in 2797 millis.
Thread-6 finished in 2798 millis.
Thread-3 finished in 2800 millis.
runMultiThreaded finished in 2812 millis.
```

Here each single thread runs faster because the super-ordinate tasks, which are main thread only,, had run by instantiating the `XSSFWorkbook` class.

Comment: Thank you for taking such a detailed look Axel! So `.run()` executes logic in the current thread, `.start()` actually starts a new thread, so the code should be ok. As you say, the key here is the JVM JIT/C2 optimizations. When you start a new thread, each thread hits it's worst performance, which then improves significantly. If you run each thread 100 times, you will see the same pattern where each run takes ~300ms after the first few iterations. There is another catch here too - POI runs XML Beans with background synchronization which reduces performance even further, turning it off helps.